# CSS3 How are zigzagged borders made?

Tags: css, border, zigzag

I have been seeing a lot of new websites that have a zigzagged border in between an image and a div. When you open the image in a new tab the zigzag is not there, so it was created either with CSS3 or HTML5. Does anyone know how it is done?

Here are some examples:

- http://themeforest.net/item/hungry-a-onepage-html-restaurant-template/full_screen_preview/9855248ref=freshdesignweb
- http://designwp.com/yummie/brown/index.html

Wait for them to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zig zag borders are made using `linear-gradient`

- 50% is the blur
- 315deg is the rotation of right side
- 45deg is the rotation of left side
- background size is the width and placement of the triangle

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 25px 120%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, red 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%), 
                    linear-gradient(45deg, red 50%, black 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

you can also change the angle of rotation by changing the `deg` values

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 25px 150%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(297deg, red 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%), 
                    linear-gradient(63deg, red 50%, black 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @eagleCDK or -45deg; it's the same

Answer (score 1):

First one is built with repeatable background image, and secound one with :before pseudo element:

```
.ss-style-top::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 25px 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #FFF 50%, transparent 50%), 
  linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF 50%, transparent 50%);
  margin-top: -30px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Here is the link of background image from first example: http://www.cssvillain.com/hungry/images/assets/parallax-bottom-alt.png